# Getting different results when using variables vs. hard-coded values?

Tags: r

I'm currently experimenting with non-linear regression in R and am playing around with different equations. I noticed I kept getting `Nan`s when using variables, but when I hard code the values, it works. Could anybody explain what is happening?

```r
a <- 200
b <- 2.5
x <- -.380654

a * x^b
#> [1] NaN
200 * -.380654^2.5
#> [1] -17.87953
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with `(-x)^2.5` vs. `-(x^2.5)`

Comment: Try `identical(-0.380654^b, -(0.380654^b))`.

Comment: You can't use negative numbers as a base in power expressions if the power is not a whole number.

Comment: I'm sure the duplicate (and the duplicate in that duplicate) relate to the issue, but a clear explanation of why the NaN occurs only _when variables are assigned_ would be helpful, to me at least!

Comment: NaN only occurs when variables are assigned due to `lazy eval`. R only does the calculations when it needs to. So the error only shows up later. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html